# Number of characters in unicode string - len() not working

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, unicode-string, string-length

I am updating some asp and vb code and have a string which I need to count the number of characters in. part of the string has non-English characters. Using len() does give the number of characters, it gives the length of the string, and because some of the characters are not in english the len() function does not work.
For example len("abc")=3 but len("אבג") is 6. The len() of the combined string is 9.

Is there a function or another way that would calculate the number of characters?

Comment: Strange,`Len` function forks for me as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem - if you save an asp page in as UTF-8 then the len() function does not work - it gives you double the number of actual characters, for non-English characters only - see example in the question.

To avoid this problem save the asp page in UTF-8 +BOM and then the len() function works correctly in all cases.